# Adding Container div Every Three Times a Loop Ends

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm writing a webpage in php to retrieve player details from a mySQL database and writing them to the body in divs, for instance:

```
<div class="infoDiv">
    <img style="margin: 10px; float:left" src="epoch.png>
    <p>Player Name: Kez</p>
    <p>Player ID: 98723947923749333432</p>
    <p>Player Morality: 0</p>
    <p>Gender: Male</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is put three of these at a time into one div, so that when two more are retrieved from the database it would end the containing div and begin a new one for the next three like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="infoDiv">
        <img style="margin: 10px; float:left" src="epoch.png>
        <p>Player Name: Kez</p>
        <p>Player ID: 98723947923749333432</p>
        <p>Player Morality: 0</p>
        <p>Gender: Male</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoDiv">
        <img style="margin: 10px; float:left" src="epoch.png>
        <p>Player Name: Kez</p>
        <p>Player ID: 98723947923749333432</p>
        <p>Player Morality: 0</p>
        <p>Gender: Male</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoDiv">
        <img style="margin: 10px; float:left" src="epoch.png>
        <p>Player Name: Kez</p>
        <p>Player ID: 98723947923749333432</p>
        <p>Player Morality: 0</p>
        <p>Gender: Male</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

. The php I'm using to write the data to the document is here:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="SELECT PlayerName,PlayerUID,PlayerMorality,PlayerSex FROM player_data";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<div class=\"infoDiv\">";
        echo "<img style=\"margin: 10px; float:left\" src=\"epoch.png\"/>";
        echo "<p>Player Name: " . $row[0] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Player ID: " . $row[1] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Player Morality: " . $row[2] . "</p>";
        if($row[3]=="0"){
            echo "<p>Gender: Male</p>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>Gender: Female</p>";
        }
        echo "</div><br>";
    }
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

I apologise in advance for this question, I know it was poorly worded, if you don't understand what I'm asking, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: you are looking for modulus-opperator? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: No, I'm trying to split the output of the query result every three times.

Comment: so you looking for it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a counter:

```
$rows_output = 0;
while(... fetch from db ...) {
   if ($rows_output % 3 == 0) { 
      ... start a new container ...
   }
   ... output row data
   if ($rows_output % 3 == 2) {
      ... just output the 3rd row, end the container ...
   }
   $rows_output++;
}
```

Comment: The notable part of this answer for OP to understand is how the modulus (`%`) operator works. It's the calculation of a remainder for a division operation. `10 / 3 = 3`, with a remainder of `1`, which is addressed by `10 % 3 = 1`. This is useful in programming (among other reasons) because when you do `$rows_output % 3`, you will always get `0`, `1`, or `2`, for every 1st, 2nd, or 3rd row in each set of 3 rows (the remainder is _never_ greater or equal to `3`!)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to put some kind of index counter in your loop and when it can be divided by three you can close current div and begin new one:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql="SELECT PlayerName,PlayerUID,PlayerMorality,PlayerSex FROM player_data";
$resultIndex = 1;

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<div class=\"infoDiv\">";
        echo "<img style=\"margin: 10px; float:left\" src=\"epoch.png\"/>";
        echo "<p>Player Name: " . $row[0] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Player ID: " . $row[1] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Player Morality: " . $row[2] . "</p>";
        if($row[3]=="0"){
            echo "<p>Gender: Male</p>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<p>Gender: Female</p>";
        }
        echo "</div><br>";

        if ($resultIndex % 3 == 0) {
            echo "</div><div class=\"container\">";
        }

        $resultIndex++;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk($array , how many per each)` and put that in a `foreach` loop like

```
foreach (array_chunk($array , 3) as $row)
{
   foreach ($row as $item)
        {
            the html goes here
        }
    // now 3 items has passed ,add something b4 the next 3
}
```